# How can I pipe STDERR to STDIN of the application running inside of bash?

Tags: bash, node.js, shell

I have a gateway bash script. The data being sent to STDERR is the data I want to pipe to the stdin of a application started by the bash script (a nodejs script).

Here is an idea of what I'm trying to do...
bash-gateway.sh:

```
#since STDERR will not continuously send data, i put a neverending while loop
#to wait for data to be present.
while (true);
do

#Read the data from STDERR and send it to server.js STDIN
cat /dev/fd/2 | node server.js;

done;
```

Comment: The parentheses around `true` aren't necessary; it just makes `true` run in a subshell, which exits with the same status as `true` itself. The semicolons are also unnecessary; newlines alone are sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't really said *what* is sending the Bash script the information. So I will assume it to be the program `foo` for the purpose of this answer. Having said that, you should be able to do something like this if you
[**just need STDERR**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/047)

```
foo 2>&1 >/dev/null | node server.js
```

if you don't mind piping both STDERR and STDOUT this would be simpler

```
foo |& node server.js
```

Comment: shell check sugggests to turn it around. `foo > /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 1):

That is what pipes were made for.

```
mkfifo needed_stderr
somecommand 2>needed_stderr
node server.js <needed_stderr
```